# C# - Custom GroupBy taking more time for large dataset

Tags: c#, .net-core

The below code groups the result (a List of ClassTypeObject with 500,000 items) into List<`a`> type.

The GroupBy takes around 40 to 50 sec when executed. Is there any way to optimize this?

```
var groupByTest = result.
                GroupBy(g => new
                {
                    First = g.Field1
                }).
                Select(gp => new
                {
                    gp.Key.Field1,
                    InnerList = result.Where(x => x.Field1 == gp.Key.Field1).ToList()
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: How long does it take if you comment out the `InnerList = result.Where(x => x.Field1 == gp.Key.Field1).ToList()` line?

Comment: Why are you selecting `InnerList` from non-grouped collection i.e. `result` You can change the inner query as `InnerList = gp.ToList()` as data is already grouped based on `Field1`.

Comment: If it's served from a DB, do you have an Index on the Grouping fields ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting `InnerList` from non-grouped collection i.e. `result` that's why your query is taking time. You can change the inner query assignment as

```
InnerList = gp.ToList()
```

as `gp` is already grouped based on `Field1`.

Full Code

```
   var groupByTest = result.
            GroupBy(g => new
            {
                First = g.Field1
            }).
            Select(gp => new
            {
                gp.Key.Field1,
                InnerList = gp.ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The way this query is written `InnerList` ends up containing just the items in the group. In its current form, the original source is scanned once for each group key. The equivalent:

```
var groupByTest = result.GroupBy(g => g.Field1)
                         .Select(gp => new {
                                        Field1=gp.Key,
                                        InnerList = gp.ToList()})
                          .ToList();
```

Would scan the source only once.

Once this is fixed, the query can be parallelized easily with `AsParallel()`

```
var groupByTest = result.AsParallel()
                        .GroupBy(g => g.Field1)
                        .Select(gp => new {
                                        Field1=gp.Key,
                                        InnerList = gp.ToList()})
                         .ToList();
```

This will use all cores in the machine to partition the data, group them and construct the final list